# Fantasy series involving possession

Tags: story-identification, urban-fantasy

I'm looking for a fantasy series that I read ~5 years ago. I don't know when it was released though.

It starts with the protagonist learning that her uncle has died, and she's been given something(?) in his will. When she arrives at her uncle's place she finds out that he wanted her to join his team that fight people who've been possessed. She finds out that he was killed by the most recent possessed person they were investigating. The team aren't that keen on her joining them though.

The plot revolves around defeating the possessed man. I remember a scene where the team go out to attack the possessed man with guns. She's unable to pull the trigger, which means that she's protected when he's able to retaliate and injure them.

There are two men on the team I specifically remember - one was a technical guy that she developed feelings for, the other was a older man (Eric?) who developed feelings for her.

The second book is set in New Orleans.

They're investigating possession in the wake of Hurricane Katrina. They find a teenager who's been possessed (or is due to be possessed?) - but there's a new ambiguity as she and her family might have a much better life if the possession happens.

There's also a plot where they're joined by a reporter who's tracking down someone who's been possessed. She ends up starting a relationship with Eric(?). At the end of the book it's revealed that she's been possessed for years.

Comment: What does "possession" mean in this context? How could one be unaware of being possessed and how could it improve one's life? I usually think of possession as some other conscious entity replacing the original person. Is that not what's happening here?

Comment: I don't remember - but it is different for each person. For the reporter she doesn't remember anything that's happened for the years that she's been possessed - the possessor has just taken over her, but hasn't made her do anything particularly evil. For the teenager it's a much more symbiotic relationship - she and the possessor will work together. I think it's something that's been happening for hundreds of years, and it gives the teenager's family power. For the antagonist in the first book it's much more a possession where the possessed man does evil things (but I don't remember what).

Comment: Hurricane Katrina was Aug 2005, to put a bound on the earliest date for the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it! It's the *[Black Sun's Daughter](https://www.goodreads.com/series/46157-the-black-sun-s-daughter)* series. Here is the synopsis for the first book, *[Unclean Spirits](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4476999-unclean-spirits)*:

> Jayné Heller thinks of herself as a realist, until she discovers reality isn't quite what she thought it was. When her uncle Eric is murdered, Jayné travels to Denver to settle his estate, only to learn that it's all hers -- and vaster than she ever imagined. And along with properties across the world and an inexhaustible fortune, Eric left her a legacy of a different kind: his unfinished business with a cabal of wizards known as the Invisible College.
>
> Led by the ruthless Randolph Coin, the Invisible College harnesses demon spirits for their own ends of power and domination. Jayné finds it difficult to believe magic and demons can even exist, let alone be responsible for the death of her uncle. But Coin sees Eric's heir as a threat to be eliminated by any means -- magical or mundane -- so Jayné had better start believing in something to save her own life.
>
> Aided in her mission by a group of unlikely companions -- Aubrey, Eric's devastatingly attractive assistant; Ex, a former Jesuit with a lethal agenda; Midian, a two-hundred-year-old man who claims to be under a curse from Randolph Coin himself; and Chogyi Jake, a self-styled Buddhist with mystical abilities -- Jayné finds that her new reality is not only unexpected, but often unexplainable. And if she hopes to survive, she'll have to learn the new rules fast -- or break them completely....

Comment: I fixed the link and added a synopsis from Goodreads for the first book.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be the [Gateway Trilogy](https://www.goodreads.com/series/107250-the-gateway-trilogy) by E.E.Holmes. I need to do some digging but I will update soon.

> These cryptic words wake college student Jess Ballard from a terrifying dream into an even more terrifying reality. Jess' life has never been what anyone would call easy; doing damage control in the wake of your nomadic, alcoholic mother doesn't exactly make for a storybook childhood. But now her world has fallen apart just when it should be coming together: her mother gone—dead under mysterious circumstances; her life uprooted to stay with estranged relatives she’s never met; and there’s something odd about some of the people she’s been meeting at school:
>
> They’re dead.
>
> Aided by Tia, her neurotic roommate, and Dr. David Pierce, a ghost-hunting professor, Jess must unravel the mystery behind her hauntings. But the closer she gets to the truth, the more danger shadows her every move. An ancient secret, long-buried, is about to claw its way to the surface, and nothing can prepare Jess for one terrifying truth...
>
> ...her encounters with the world of the dead are only just beginning.

Comment: It's not this I'm afraid - thanks though.